# Applications of mean and standard deviation

Tags: average, standard-deviation, means

If I have this set of numbers: `[9,7,5,5,4,4,4,2]`
We know that:
mean = 5
variance = 4
standard deviation = 2
But is there an application/formula of standard deviation to give us a hint that the trend of the numbers is downwards?

Comment: Is there more context than you have posted ?

Comment: @callculus:I am interested in figuring out if a set of numbers is having a negative trend and I was thinking that the variance would show us if the numbers get more diverse towards extremes. Also my numbers are non-negative decimal numbers (0 included)

Comment: I think you cannot say anything about the trend without additional information. Why shouldn´t be the next 3 numbers 100 each ?

Comment: @callculus:These are random numbers representing events. The next could be anything yes

Answer (score 0):

If you let these numbers be $y$ values and allow corresponding $x$ values to be $1,2,3...$ and paired in sequence with the $y$ values, you could calculate the PMCC or the equation of the regression line.

Comment: Are you talking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient?

Comment: Yes but the gradient of the regression line might be what you want, since the PMCC measures closeness to a line rather than how fast it decreases

Comment: The issue is that my data do not form a line. They are scattered and the graph would be with highs and lows. My intention was to find if in this graph we are starting to see a fast downward trend (i.e. some kind of downward spike) towards the end of the graph. Hence I was considering standard deviation. So my set of numbers represent the graph completely and the graph is not a line

Comment: It doesn't matter if they don't form an exact line. The gradient of the regression line will give a value to the amount $y$ decreases as $x$ increases